# Calculating raster standard deviation in a memory efficient way in R

Tags: raster, r

I am trying to calculate `standard deviation` between two `NDVI` `rasters` stacked together using the `raster::calc` function in `R`. Both of these stacked rasters are `355 MB` in size, and I have `4.2 GB` of `RAM` available out of `16 GB`. Now the `calc` function is giving me an error:

```
  Error: memory exhausted (limit reached?)
```

How can the memory issue be solved?

```
library(raster)

NDVI1 =  raster("path/NDVI1.tif")
NDVI2 =  raster("path/NDVI2.tif")

NDVI1= resample(NDVI1, NDVI1)

NDVI_Stack = stack(NDVI1, NDVI2)

NDVI_Std = calc(NDVI_Stack, fun = sd)
```

Comment: Can you check current memory size allocation? `memory.limit()`

Comment: Deleting some raster layers in the `RStudio`  environment, and freeing up additional space in the drive solved the problem.

Comment: `sd` is the "standard deviation", not "stand deviation". I don't know if there is a thing called the "stand deviation", but `sd` isn't it. Have edited the Q.

Comment: @Spacedman, yes sorry, that was a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is odd; it suggests that something is missed in assessing the memory needs.  You can check for yourself what is going on under the hood with

```
canProcessInMemory(NDVI_Stack, verbose=TRUE)
```

And you can allow `raster` to use *less* memory, for example like this

```
rasterOptions(memfrac=.3)
```

(and/or using smaller chunk-sizes), see `?rasterOptions`. And see the difference

```
canProcessInMemory(NDVI_Stack, verbose=T)
```

And try `calc` again.

Reducing the RAM that raster can use will slow it down, so you would not generally do that. In fact, others will increase it to speed things up.

None of this should normally be necessary. While there are some corner cases I am a bit surprised about this happening, and it would be useful if you edited your question to show what `canProcessInMemory(NDVI_Stack, verbose=TRUE)` and `sessionInfo()` return.

If the values of `NDVI1` are in memory it may help to write it to disk so that more RAM stays available

```
 NDVI1 <- writeRaster(NDVI1, "temp.tif")
```

Or in one swoop

```
 NDVI1 = resample(NDVI1, NDVI1, filename="temp.tif")
```

By the way, you say that your rasters have a size of 355 MB, but I assume that this is the size on disk, which can be much smaller than the size in memory, because of compression and the use of, e.g., byte sized values instead of the 8 times larger (double) floating point values they become in R.

Finally, if you try the *development version* of `terra`, which you can install like this:

```
 `install.packages('terra', repos='https://rspatial.r-universe.dev')
```

You can do

```
library(terra)
NDVI1 =  rast("path/NDVI1.tif")
NDVI2 =  rast("path/NDVI2.tif")
NDVI1 = resample(NDVI1, NDVI1)
NDVI_Stack = c(NDVI1, NDVI2)
```

And compute the **sample sd** (denominator is *n-1*) like this:

```
NDVI_Std_sample = app(NDVI_Stack, fun = sd)
```

Or the **population sd** (denominator is *n*) like this:

```
NDVI_Std_pop = stdev(NDVI_Stack)
```